# WildFly 9 loading jar from deployed war using ContextClassLoader

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have deployed on war under WildFly-9.0.2 and in java code I want to get absolute path for one of the jar which is available under `helloworld.war/WEB-INF/lib/` directory, I am trying with following java code

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/lib/demo.jar/")
```

This was working in JBoss 4.0.5, but in WildFly 9 it gives null,

If I try with following code

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("")
```

Then I can see the file as follow, but for this I have to iterate through all the return collections,

```
vfs:/C:/Users/alpesh/Desktop/content/helloworld.war/WEB-INF/lib/demo.jar/
```

So, how can I directly locate the jar path as I was doing on earlier JBoss.

Comment: What do you want to do with the resource?

Comment: basically that jar having the code which create new database based on user selection and populate predefined data in that new database, there are more than 1 jar for creating different databases as per user selection

Comment: Needing get a reference to the actual JAR seems a bit odd. I don't know for sure, but I'd guess that the `WEB-INF/lib` directory is not readable. Using an EJB or something similar you could invoke would avoid having to get the URL to the JAR.